# Dickey-Fuller test asymptotic distribution

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

In Shumway & Stoffer, *Time Series Analysis and Its Applications*, it is argued in Section 5.3 that the limiting random variable for the Dickey-Fuller test statistic is 
$$ \frac{\chi_1^2 - 1}{2(\int_0^1 W^2(t) \, d t)},$$
where $\chi_1^2$ is a Chi-Square distributed rv with one degree of freedom, and $W$ is a standard Brownion motion; see Eq (5.32).

However, at first sight in the derivation of this result the authors assume (or at least suggest) independence of numerator and denominator, which is not discussed in any detail.

Does anybody know if the above expression is indeed correct for the Dickey-Fuller test statistic, and whether $\chi_1^2$ and $(W(t))$ can be assumed to be independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above expression can also be found in Hamilton's Time Series Analysis, p. 488, while in the preceding pages there one can find how it is derived.

As regards the "independence" issue, the answer is NO, the numerator and the denominator are not independent (but this does not affect the derivation of the limiting distribution).

(Note for new comers: the denominator, even though a definite integral, is a random variable, not a constant).

Comment: Thank you Alecos. If I am not mistaken, I now understand that the limiting random variable is in fact $\frac{W(1)^2-1}{2 \int_0^1 W(t)^2 \, ds}$, which makes the dependence explicit.

Comment: @JorisBierkens Yes, that's correct.